# Странно отображаются вопросы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом ответы выглядят нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема? Как чинить? Браузер - Chrome 102

Comment: ещё под рекламой строка в кодировке UTF-16 : "Пожаловаться на эту рекламу" чуток раздражает.

Comment: это на всех вопросах? или на каком-то конкретном?

Comment: У меня нет такого.

Comment: @Qwertiy на всех. Открывается сразу нормально, потом буквально через секунду становится таким как на скринах.

Comment: Вопрос не по теме: а почему вы рекламу не отключите?.. У Вас более чем достаточно репутации для этого.

Comment: @МихаилРебров отличное предложение (сарказм беззлобный), сегодня принесло мне такие же проблемы и на винде. И вот это уже начинает раздражать.

Comment: Что за новичок отвечает за верстку? (Я через мак в хроме смотрю если что)

Comment: @МихаилРебров она отключается где-то? В принципе, она мне не мешает, но если это решит проблему, то почему бы и нет.

Comment: `Профиль` > `Настройки` > `Предпочтения` > `Реклама` > `Включить рекламу` ( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/200881 ) - Переключатель должен быть выключен

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/wWfGTzY.png

Comment: @Dmitry , я прекрасно понимаю, что это не избавляет никого от сути проблемы... Просто искренне удивился (я уже давно отвык от рекламы)

Comment: @smellyshovel решит частично. Реклама об опросе останется

Comment: @МихаилРебров интересно, что у меня этого пункта нет (на отключение рекламы).

Comment: Только что через девтулзы браузерные удалил просто div  с рекламой - помогает. Осталось только понять, почему я ее выключить не могу

Comment: А, все. Это я настройки меты смотрел.

Comment: @smellyshovel может вы на мете в настройках профиля смотрите? (на мете такой настройки и нет) смотреть нужно именно на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: В общем да, проблема решилась. Реклама справа осталась, и под ней тот же непонятный текст, что у человека в ответе ниже. Но это не критично. Теперь хотя бы вопрос прочитать можно. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: на stackexchange соответствующий багрепорт появился https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383153/multibyte-characters-for-report-this-ad-string-are-broken

Answer (score 1):

протестил на windows, нет такого. Но на Chrome на macOS, тоже дичь какая то вылезает (unicode последовательность) в правой части под предложением об опросе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На Windows не проверял, проблема у меня на линуксе

Comment: @smellyshovel , у меня тоже Linux, но я пока не смог воспроизвести.